# InsufficientS3BucketPolicyFault when enabling AWS Redshift audit logging through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

### Problem

I'm trying to enable audit logging on an AWS redshift cluster. I've been following the instructions provided by AWS here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/db-auditing.html#db-auditing-enable-logging

### Current Configuration

I've defined the relevant IAM role as follows

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "example-role" {
  name = "example-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "redshift.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF

}
```

And have granted the following IAM permissions to the `example-role` role:

```
{
            "Sid": "AllowAccessForAuditLogging",
            "Effect": "Allow",

            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
```

The relevant portion of the redshift cluster configuration is as follows:

```
resource "aws_redshift_cluster" "example-cluster-name" {
  cluster_identifier = "example-cluster-name"
  ...

  # redshift audit logging to S3
  logging {
    enable        = true
    bucket_name   = "example-bucket-name"
  }

  master_username           = var.master_username
  iam_roles                 = [aws_iam_role.example-role.arn]
  ...
```

### Error

`terraform plan` runs correctly, and produces the expected plan based on the above configuration. However, when running `terraform apply` the following error occurs:

```
Error: error enabling Redshift Cluster (example-cluster-name) logging: InsufficientS3BucketPolicyFault: Cannot read ACLs of bucket example-bucket-name. Please ensure that your IAM permissions are set up correctly.
```

note: i've replaced all resource identifiers with example-* resource names and identifiers.

Comment: You need to put your role as a bucket policy. Probably you're attaching it as IAM role?

Comment: you're right, that did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@shimo's answer is correct. I just detail for someone like me

- Redshift has full access to S3. But you need add bucket policy too. ( S3's permission)

```
{
           "Sid": "Statement1",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": {
               "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::361669875840:user/logs"
           },
           "Action": [
               "s3:GetBucketAcl",
               "s3:PutObject"
           ],
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::<your-bucket>",
               "arn:aws:s3:::<your-bucket>/*"
           ]
       }
 
- `361669875840` is match with your region check [here][1]


 [1]: https://github.com/finos/compliant-financial-infrastructure/blob/main/aws/redshift/redshift_template_public.yml
```